# Creating folder on Ubuntu with war deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I have a deployed war with Tomcat on Ubuntu. When I try to create a folder, this folder is not created. The folder path is /orders/ and the Java code is:

```
File tmpDir = new File("/orders/1);
if (!tmpDir.exists()) {
        tmpDir.mkdir();
}
```

I have a try/catch, but any exception is thrown.

The permission of my folder is:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 May 28 20:51 orders
```

And trying to show what user execute Tomcat, I can see that is root:

```
pas aux | grep apache

root     26890  1.2  3.4 4507084 412560 pts/7  Sl   20:46   0:14 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties .....
```

When I look into this folder I can't see anything...

**What is the Problem?**

Tomcat permission? Where can I see that? Or maybe I don't have the path in web.xml or some place?

**SOLUTION by @Harald:**

In Java 7 is better use Files.createDirectories() than mkdir(). Mkdir doesn't work for me.

Comment: These days (from Java 7), prefer `Files.createDirectories()` over `File.mkdir()` for a variety of reasons, one being that it throws an exception with meaningful name, while `mkdir` only returns true or false. The exceptions message will likely tell you, what the problem is.

Comment: You name Ubuntu in the title and tags, ArchLinux in the question. What is it?

Comment: @Harald Lot of thanks, It works!!. But now i can't create images... What method can I use? Currently i am using :
 Files.write(destinationFile, decodedImg)

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock, now is edited. It is an ubuntu server, i was wrong.